# What is the recommended way to store video in elasticsearch?

Tags: java, video, upload, elasticsearch

I have a sample use case, where I would like to store  MJPEG videos and its meta-information such as date of video creation, video location, name etc. Storing all other information is fine, but I have no gain in storing video data to elastic search as it plays no role in searching. So I have a big confusion about whether to store video in elastic search or store it at another data store. Please suggest. If it has to be stored at elasticsearch, how can I achieve it using java. Does storing video to Elastic search pays for performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The video could be stored in Elasticsearch using the [Attachment](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-attachment-type.html) plugin or storing it in a [binary](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html#binary) type.

However, as you suggest storing it **outside** of Elasticsearch may be better, store a link to the video in ES and have your application find the video using the link instead.

In my environment I store enough data in ES to allow users to search and bring back matching search results - when they select an entry to see more details the information is coming from an Oracle DB instead.